# Strange/Inconsistent SSIS row import error

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I'm importing a csv non-unicode file using SSIS into SQL Server. I get the error "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page". It fails in column 0 on row 70962, which has data just like every other row; the data in the first column is no longer than the data in rows above it.

My column 0 is defined in the flat file connection, and in the database, as 255 wide. The data in row 70692 (and most other rows) is 17 characters.

The strange thing is, if I remove a row above row 70962 in the file, even the first row, and save the csv file, then the import runs fine. If I replace that removed row, and run the import, it fails again.

So I'm not even sure how to identify what the issue is.

If I create a new flat file connection that is a single column, I can import the whole file into a single-column table. But as soon as I add the first column delimiter (i.e. second column), then it fails on that same row.

At the moment I'm just short of idea as to how to debug this further.

Comment: Times like this, I pull out [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) to look for gremlins in the data. The other option is to write a quick parser in .NET to try and find the unmatched rows

Answer (score 0):

You already gave the answer in your question ;)

> if I remove a row above row 70962 in the file, even the first row, and
>   save the csv file, then the import runs fine.

You have a broken delimiter somewhere in the file. when you remove any data before the offending line the mismatch of delimiters is probably not properly handled but simply left open until the very end of the file after which the program handles it for you.

Check the row and column delimiters of the row above the one you mentioned and that very row.

Comment: The row directly above looks fine, too. I'm not sure about the logic: surely if I remove Row 1, and Row 1 is not problematic, the error should still arise?

Comment: If there is a delimiter too much or missing in any row removing a different row can sometimes "offset" this due too the difference being "pushed" to the end of the file.

Comment: There's no discernable issue with the row directly above, so could the issue then be on any one of the previous 70961 rows? Can I disable it from pushing the error around, and get it to error on the appropriate row - i.e. strict delimiter checking?

Comment: there are some csv file "health check" tools around but simply pasting in excel and seeing where it gets jumbled is usually faster. You can often see the area with the problem at 20% zoom

Comment: Not having any luck. Like finding a needle in a haystack

Comment: What makes it worse is I have an odd delimiter: "," (including the quotes, because one of the fields has quotes in the data). So importing into Excel is not helping because I can't specify multiple character delimiters.

Comment: the quotes aren't delimiters as such. they are text qualifiers and excel can handle those just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60526/discussion-between-sean-and-tristan).